# How to fix type 'Future<RssFeed>' is not a subtype of type 'RssFeed?' error - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a podcast streaming app and am getting the error "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'RssFeed?' " as I navigate to my podcast data screen which loads but with no data present.

The error occurs as I try to assign the returned RssFeed from my initData() function (using the webfeed package) to a variable (showData) of type "RssFeed?" in initState.

The code is below that keeps throwing the error:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    try {
      showData = initData() as RssFeed;
    } catch (e) {
      print('initPodScreenError: $e');
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  RssFeed? showData;

  Future<RssFeed> initData() async {
    try {
      RssFeed data = await PodcastData().getdata(widget.showURL!);
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      print('podcastScreenDataError: $e');
      throw Exception('podcastScreenDataError: $e');
    }
  }
```

I've tried multiple ways of changing up the variable type definitions and no matter what I keep getting this error. The error just changes to include whatever I change anything to whether it be the return type of initData() function or the showData variable

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ2qb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGFSG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    initData();
    super.initState();
  }

  RssFeed? showData;

  Future<void> initData() async {
    try {
      RssFeed data = await PodcastData().getdata(widget.showURL!);
      setState((){
       showData = data;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('podcastScreenDataError: $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `initState` async. It would be better if you use `FutureBuilder`.

Also can be done.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
    try {
      initData().then((value){
       showData= value;
       setState((){}) ;
       });
    } catch (e) {
      print('initPodScreenError: $e');
    }
  }
```